# How to take picture in camera app programatically using accessibility service via Bluetooth BLE device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, camera, accessibility

I have Bluetooth (BLE) device where when I click button I want to perform action to capture photo or video in default camera app.

There are many Bluetooth devices (mostly from China) which "remotely take photo" when you are in default camera application with a single click of a button.

I searched the internet for the past month and I cou'dn't find a way how to perform the action to "click" on button in the camera app.

There are lots of tutorials how to do it via increasing volume up or down to perform capture image, but it does not work because you need special system permission to perform it via AudioManager.FLAG_FROM_KEY, but for that you need rooted device.

Another tutorial showed how to find the "button" via accessibilityEvent and find in currently opened application (camera app) text "Take photo" and perform a click action. This does not work, because many default application now don't have hidden text/label to the button.

Does anyone have any idea where to start looking or experience?

---

Example code:

**MyAccessibilityService.java**

```java
public class MyAccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
{
    public static AccessibilityService getInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    public void takePhoto() {
        // How to take photo ?
    }

    // ...
```

**RandomClassWhereWeCallTheTakePhotoMethodFrom.java**

```java
public void onSingleClick() {
    myAccessibilityService = MyAccessibilityService.getInstance();
    myAccessibilityService.takePhoto();
}
```

---

What I mean by clicking on "button" in the camera app:
[image: phone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "chinese" triggers all use HID over GATT to simulate a volume button press, i.e. like a Bluetooth keyboard. That way you can pair it directly in the System settings. No app needed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you should be able to just send a [VOLUME_UP key code](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) to the phone (I only tested on a Samsung S21 though). Not knowing how you set your Bluetooth up, I can't offer much in terms of code, but [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/ble-hid-keyboard-buttons-with-circuitpython?view=all) have a really comprehensive tutorial and libraries. [Silicon labs' documentation](https://docs.silabs.com/bluetooth/2.13/code-examples/applications/ble-hid-keyboard) also looks fairly promising for explaining all the details on a lower level.

### Edit 10 March 2023: Sending a keycode in BLE C++

I was asked in the comment how to send this keycode, which I mentioned I am not sure of the particular BLE implementation. I am assuming Arduino C++, because I have nothing else to go on. In other parts of the answer I do reference [Adafruit for a python version](https://learn.adafruit.com/ble-hid-keyboard-buttons-with-circuitpython?view=all)

```
#include <BleKeyboard.h>

BleKeyboard bleKeyboard;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");
  bleKeyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(bleKeyboard.isConnected()) {
    Serial.println("Sending 'Hello world'...");
    bleKeyboard.print("Hello world");

    delay(1000);

    Serial.println("Sending Volume Up Key...");
    bleKeyboard.write(KEY_MEDIA_VOLUME_UP); // edited for the purpose of this answer

    delay(1000);

    Serial.println("Sending Play/Pause media key...");
    bleKeyboard.write(KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);

    delay(1000);

  }
  Serial.println("Waiting 5 seconds...");
  delay(5000);
}
```

[Code Source](https://github.com/T-vK/ESP32-BLE-Keyboard)
[Arduino key codes](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/keyboardmodifiers/)

I did try to compare the [Android KeyCode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) with the [C++ Keyboard Library keycode](https://github.com/T-vK/ESP32-BLE-Keyboard/blob/c96bc0e8f2e98a277c75a1491bedbaf944b5c6ce/BleKeyboard.h#L110) and they seem different, but I imagine there is probably some fancy mathematics, not the actual code.

If you wanted to send a keycode in Android, you can test it with the adb:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
```

or in a Java app:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP);
```

-- end edit 10 March 2023

### A long note on Accessibility Services and their usage.

An [accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) for this particular problem is probably too much work and not likely going to be well received if you ever intend to publish your app to the Play Store:

> Accessibility services should only be used to assist users with disabilities in using Android devices and apps.

Many apps that have been abusing the purpose of accessibility services have already been removed from the store, leading to a requirement that apps must declare an [`isAccessibilityTool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AccessibilityService_isAccessibilityTool) flag in their manifest:

> Google Play permits the use of the AccessibilityService API for a wide range of applications. However, only services that are designed to help people with disabilities access their device or otherwise overcome challenges stemming from their disabilities are eligible to declare that they are accessibility tools. This is done using the isAccessibilityTool attribute in the service’s metadata file. [Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10964491?hl=en)

Your users might not appreciate seeing the privacy notice (which is about granting your app privileged access):

> Attribute indicating whether the accessibility service is used to assist users with disabilities. This criteria might be defined by the installer. The default is false.
>
> Note: If this flag is false, system will show a notification after a duration to inform the user about the privacy implications of the service. [Source](https://learn.adafruit.com/ble-hid-keyboard-buttons-with-circuitpython?view=all)

Comment: How can you dispatch the VOLUME_UP key code programatically (how the code could looks like, how can I use it ?)

Comment: I have added a C++ example for your BLE controller. As I am unsure what your input device is coded in, I guessed C++. I also added an ADB command you can use for testing, and a way to do it from a Java Android application